# Altering Code in .R File via Trace() to Give Correct Output in Terminal

Tags: r, function, terminal, trace, hpc

I am using package Rphylip, function Rdnadist(), in RStudio Version 1.1.447/R 3.4.4 on my Mac as well as on R/3.4.0 within a computer cluster (UMass GHPCC). While my script that I wrote on R runs all the way through on RStudio as well as when I submit a job to the cluster, the final output is incorrect. I figured out the source and have been trying to fix it but to no avail.

Rphylip uses setPath() to connect to phylip-3.697/exe folder on my directory. This gives access to programs that are part of PHYLIP. One of these programs is ./dnadist, which in R is Rdnadist. If you look at my .out file after the job runs when it gets to ./dnadist:

[image: see here]

Normally, if I was just doing it manually, I'd type "I" to make my input sequences sequential. However, this is through Rdnadist in a .R file with no option to have it change "I" in the arguments offered. I went into the code itself of Rdnadist to see if I could alter it. I did this with trace() as well as fix() within RStudio. However, everytime I run the script I keep seeing the settings unchanged for "I".

Here's the body(Rdnadist):

```
{
method <- method[1]
if (is.null(path)) 
    path <- findPath("dnadist")
if (is.null(path)) 
    stop("No path provided and was not able to find path to dnadist")
if (class(X) != "DNAbin") 
    stop("X should be an object of class 'DNAbin'")
if (hasArg(quiet)) 
    quiet <- list(...)$quiet
else quiet <- FALSE
if (!quiet) 
    if (file.warn(c("infile", "outfile", "weights")) == 0) 
        return(NULL)
oo <- c("r")
ee <- vector()
if (method != "F84") 
    oo <- c("r", rep("d", which(c("K80", "JC", "LogDet", 
        "similarity") == method)))
if (hasArg(gamma)) {
    gamma <- list(...)$gamma
    oo <- c(oo, "g")
    ee <- c(ee, 1/sqrt(gamma))
}
if (hasArg(kappa)) {
    kappa <- list(...)$kappa
    oo <- c(oo, "t", kappa)
}
if (hasArg(rates)) {
    rates <- list(...)$rates
    if (hasArg(rate.categories)) {
        rate.categories <- list(...)$rate.categories
        write(paste(rate.categories, collapse = ""), file = "categories")
        ncats <- length(rates)
        rates <- paste(rates, collapse = " ")
        oo <- c(oo, "c", ncats, rates)
    }
    else {
        warning("cannot use rates argument without rate categories; ignoring argument rates")
        rates <- NULL
    }
}
else rates <- NULL
if (hasArg(weights)) {
    oo <- c(oo, "w")
    write(paste(weights, collapse = ""), file = "weights")
}
else weights <- NULL
if (hasArg(bf)) {
    bf <- list(...)$bf
    bf <- bf/sum(bf)
    bf <- paste(bf, collapse = " ")
    oo <- c(oo, "f", bf)
}
oo <- c(oo, ee, "y")
system("touch outfile")
write.dna(X)
system(paste(path, "/dnadist", sep = ""), input = oo, show.output.on.console = (!quiet))
temp <- readLines("outfile")
xx <- strsplit(paste(temp, collapse = " "), " ")[[1]]
xx <- xx[xx != ""]
D <- matrix(NA, nrow(X), nrow(X))
for (i in 1:nrow(X)) D[i, ] <- as.numeric(xx[1:nrow(X) + 
    (i - 1) * (nrow(X) + 1) + 2])
rownames(D) <- colnames(D) <- rownames(X)
if (hasArg(cleanup)) 
    cleanup <- list(...)$cleanup
else cleanup <- TRUE
if (cleanup) 
    cleanFiles(c("infile", "outfile"))
return(as.dist(D)) }
```

I have tried altering lines 8 or 16 using fix() OR tried line 17 via trace() to include:

```
oo<-c("r", "I")
```

or

```
oo<-c("r", ee, "I", "y")
```

respectively. I also tried writing:

```
if (hasArg(input)) {
oo <- c(oo, "i")}
```

and used input ="i" in the arguments just to see if that worked.

I am completely stuck and not sure how else to get it automatically change "I" when it runs the script... any advice?

EDIT: I wanted to put down what I see in the job's .out file when I use trace()...

Here's the line of code:

```
trace(Rdnadist, quote(oo <- c(oo, ee, "I", "y")), at=17)
```

And then when running in RStudio or R/3.4.0 module in terminal I see this:

```
[1] "Rdnadist"
Tracing FUN(X[[i]], ...) step 17
```

So it appears it is indeed running the edit I made in the function? However, further in the .out file... [image: see here].

Therefore, "I" is still not being changed even though "r" and "y" have worked. ("r" tells it to replace the previous file and "y" let's it begin the program). I am still getting warnings because "I" was not changed.

Comment: i think `fix` is meant to be used in interactive mode. a similar approach would be to  try something like `x <- as.list(body(Rdnadist)); x[c(8, 16)] <- list(quote(oo<-c("r", "I")), quote(oo<-c("r", ee, "I", "y"))); body(Rdnadist) <- as.call(x)` but i will probably get yelled at for suggesting such monstrosity

Comment: I will try it now and post back in a few, the other concern is I *think* that's where "I" should go in order for it to be inputted into script - I am not sure if maybe I am wrong in interpreting what the Rdnadist sciprt is saying?

Comment: oh i'm not sure what you need to do, I was just suggesting how you could do the thing you tried to do

Comment: Just tried your suggestion @rawr and still no avail, it is using my input file as interleaved sequences rather than sequential. I know this because I'll get -1 in my distance matrix and warning saying "differences between species # and # too large to estimate distance -1 was written" ... this error doesn't occur if it knows they are sequential sequences...

Comment: No worries, I appreciate any advice @rawr! Worth a shot :)

Comment: can you set `cleanup = FALSE` and check the infile/outfile to see if the options are being passed correctly? also it seems you could skip this and edit the line with the `system` command where the `"I"` should be passed in `input = oo`

Comment: @rawr I can still see the output when I send a job despite cleanup=TRUE. I made edits in my question to give additional information in regards to that. Can you explain a bit more in detail in how to use system() within Rdnadist script?

Comment: I was just saying that it looks like a simple function that is only setting up an `dnadist` command to be passed to `system` which then reads the output and gives you the distance matrix. So you could just circumvent this process by writing your system command just as `Rdnadist` would but with the interleave option. Or just copy the function, make your changes, and add it to the script. If you have two functions called `Rdnadist`, the one in your global environment will be preferred

Answer (score 1):

While I couldn't get the trace() function to stick for Rdnadist or a way to tell Rdnadist to change "I"... I figured out a way to circumvent further up in my script and wanted to share in case others get stuck like I did when trying run these PHYLIP programs with Rphylip:

```
seqs <- readRNAStringSet("DataSubSet15Fasta.fasta")
aligned <- AlignSeqs(seqs)
#class "RNAStringSet
dnaaligned<-DNAStringSet(aligned, use.names=TRUE)
#class "Biostrings"
writeXStringSet(dnaaligned, file="dnaalignedDataSubSet15Fasta.fasta")
#read in fasta as DNAbin
sequences <- read.dna("dnaalignedDataSubSet15Fasta.fasta",format="fasta")
#class "DNAbin"
```

You can run this through Rseqboot (which has an interleaved format) and which then can go through Rdnadist correctly wihthout getting "-1" in your matrices. I did email Dr. Revell yesterday to see if there is a way going in with a sequential file and telling Rdnadist this - if he replies I'll post that answer too. For now, at least this is something.

Oh, and if you want to save files as you go you can do this:

```
write.dna(sequences,file="Aligned16S_Final.phy",format="interleaved")
#converting phylip file to DNAbin
Aligned16S_Final<-read.dna("Aligned16S_Final.phy", format= "interleaved")
class(Aligned16S_Final)
#class "DNAbin" - whatever format you put in (sequential or interleaved), it keeps it
```